# Fazer uma contagem no banco Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Bom dia .

Queria fazer um select em meu banco e retornasse a quantidade de cadastrados .

Exemplo:

tb_cliente;
coluna: dt_cadastro;

na coluna dt_cadastro tenho isso:

```
2000-01-20
2001-10-05
1990-11-09
1990-07-16
1990-08-10
```

Eu queria fazer um select assim:

```
SELECT dt_cadastro, count(dt_cadastro)
FROM tb_cliente
WHERE dt_cadastro < 2000
GROUP BY dt_cadastro
```

Ou seja, quero saber quantos são menores que 2000 e não estou conseguindo.

Seguindo a sugestão do **@Motta**, usei isso:

```
SELECT dt_cadastro , count(dt_cadastro )
FROM tb_cliente
WHERE  Extract(year from dt_cadastro ) = Extract(year from '1990-12-31'::DATE)
GROUP BY dt_nasc
```

Só que o resultado foi:

```
"1990-01-01";1
"1990-08-02";1
"1990-08-08";1
```

Eu precisava que aparecesse o valor **3**, é possível?

Comment: WHERE extract(year from dt_cadastro) < 2000    https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @Motta vou editar minha pergunta acrescentado sua sugestão.

Comment: Tenta assim `SELECT count(dt_cadastro )
FROM tb_cliente
WHERE  Extract(year from dt_cadastro ) = Extract(year from '1990-12-31'::DATE)
GROUP BY dt_nasc`

Comment: @R.Santos não deu... apareceu 1
1
1

Comment: Altera o group by para `Group by dt_cadastro` vê o que da

Comment: @Vilma Deu certo?

Comment: @R.Santos tb não. Consegui usando isso: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_cliente WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_cadastro) = 1980;    Agora vou ver como usar isso com o criteria do Hibernate.

Comment: @Vilma Tenta assim então `select count(*) from tb_cliente where dt_cadastro < '1999-12-31'` Testei aqui no meu banco de dados e deu certinho, se der certo só avisa

Comment: @R.Santos, não deu. Estou usando, como disse anteriormente esse: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_cliente WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_cadastro) = 1980;  e está funcionando do jeito que quero. Vou apenas converter isso para o criteria do hibernate.

Comment: Estranho, no meu banco de dados PostgreSQL deu certo, trazendo apenas o valor de `Count`, mas se deu certo assim melhor

Answer (score 1):

A solução na sua pergunta está correta, porém no `SELECT` você deve colocar somente as opções que você quer "ver", veja o `SQL` abaixo se é o que você realmente precisa:

```
SELECT COUNT(dt_cadastro) -- no select vai somente a informação que você quer ver
  FROM tb_cliente
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_cadastro) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '1990-12-31'::DATE)
 GROUP BY dt_nasc
```

Answer (score -1):

Solução encontrada:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_cliente WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_cadastro) =
>   1980;